# Can't link in libnanomsg for Windows MinGW, cross compiling using MXE

Tags: c, mingw, static-linking, mxe, nanomsg

I am trying to build nanomsg on mingw, cross compiling from ubuntu using mxe. The target host is x86_64. I built it fine but it won't link. I am getting issues like

```
undefined reference to 'imp__nn_freemsg'
```

I think it's a static lib issue. I built again using

```
 ./configure --enable-static --disable-shared ...
```

Same issue. Are there any linker flags I need to put in the gcc build line after I link in libnanomsg.a?

Comment: Yes! There are many defines that will be set if you build with VS, using cmake. Some are located in src/nn.h, others are scattered around. By the way, the 'imp__**' issue is always a failure to link it statically.    -D_WIN32 -DNN_EXPORTS -DNN_HAVE_MINGW -DNN_HAVE_WINDOWS -DNN_USE_LITERAL_IFADDR=1 -DSTATICLIB will fix it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are many defines that will be set if you build with VS, using cmake. Some are located in src/nn.h, others are scattered around. By the way, the 'imp__**' issue is always a failure to link it statically.

Passing these flags will link it:

> -D_WIN32 -DNN_EXPORTS -DNN_HAVE_MINGW -DNN_HAVE_WINDOWS -DNN_USE_LITERAL_IFADDR=1 -DSTATICLIB